# Do I need to state that I parts of my code are under the MIT License

Tags: ionic-framework

So I'm making a commercial app using the Ionic Mobile Framework. I know that the framework is free to use and distribute, as it is under the MIT License. However, does this mean that somewhere in my app I need to include the MIT License or acknowledge Ionic in any way? I used many of the components found on http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#header with some or no change in addition to the framework itself.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

MIT license says, if you are using a portion of the code or a file of any open source application that are licensed under MIT license then you should include a MIT license and copyright for original or modified clause/file.

Since MIT license is a permissive license. It will not block you from doing any future work nor in commercial application. It gives you a complete freedom to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sub-license, and/or sell copies.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the URLS that might help you with your concerns.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/46380/how-do-i-use-gpl-and-mit-licenses-correctly

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/318100/may-i-include-parts-of-mit-licensed-code-inside-my-closed-source-project